# pattern name for override view templates

Tags: views, theming, 8

Twig template - `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` contains :

```
#}
{% if title %}
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
{%
set row_classes = [
default_row_class ? 'views-row',
]
%}
<div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
{{ row.content }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to insert a `<hr>` tag after each `</div>`:

```
<div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
{{ row.content }}
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

It works, but for all and every `{{ row.content }}`. I want to do it **only for certain views-blocks**. Twig debugging offers me to theme a whole block (for example: `block--views-block--news-left-block-1.html.twig`) and I need something like views-view-unformatted--news-left-block-1.html.twig or some other way to insert the tag.

what is the correct filename to override view template?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Just use  `views-view-unformatted--(your view block name).html.twig`.
Eg. If your view name is Slideshow, use views-view-unformatted--slideshow.html.twig

This is a good reference point - http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates

Answer (score 6):

The pattern for override view template is

views-view-DISPLAYNAME--VIEWS_MACHINENAME--DISPLAY_MACHINENAME.html.twig

if you don't consider *--DISPLAY_MACHINENAME* the template will be used for all displays on  *VIEWS_MACHINENAME* view.

in your case

**DISPLAYNAME =** unformatted
**DISPLAY_MACHINENAME =** news-left
**DISPLAY_MACHINENAME =** block-1

So  your file pattern is

```
 views-view-unformatted--news-left.html.twig
```

or

```
views-view-unformatted--news-left--block-1.html.twig
```

**Note :** if your machine name contain "_"(underscore) convert all of them to "-".

Comment: Very clear and crisp information :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update if you're on Drupal 9**

Twig **doesn't** seem to use the templates named with with a hyphen in place of underscores.

If:

- View Format = unformatted
- View Machine Name = my_view
- View Page/Block Machine Name= myviewpage

This appears to be the file that twig uses:

```
views-view-unformatted--my_view.html.twig
```

It ignores the following even if they exist:

```
views-view-unformatted--my_view--myviewpage.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--my-view--myviewpage.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--my-view.html.twig
```