# How can I add a wrapper to a group by in Drupal 8 views?

Tags: views, 8

I have a (drupal 8.3) view using group by that outputs html like:

```
<div class="view-content">
  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
  <div class="view-row"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to hook or template the group by to use a wrapper and achieve:

```
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="group-wrapper">
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group-wrapper">
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
    <div class="view-row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this using Bootstrap theme?

Comment: Please follow https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163801/pattern-name-for-override-view-templates link to override template and add a class as its done in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/views-add-a-wrapper-div-around-a-group link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by customizing the views-view-unformatted.html.twig file:

- Use [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) to determine which version of this template is currently being used. Most likely, it's `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` in /core/modules/views/templates
- Copy that file to your theme's templates folder.
- Rename the template to this: `views-view-unformatted--your-view--your-display.html.twig` where `your-view` is the machine name of your view and `your-display` is the machine name of your view display.
- Add this code to the template file you created:

  ```
  <div class="group-wrapper">
    {% for row in rows %}
      {%
      set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
      ]
      %}
    <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {% if loop.first and title  %}
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
          {% endif %}
          {{ row.content }}
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  ```
- Flush your site's caches

Please note that spaces in your machine name are repalced with dashes in the name of the template file.