# Changing the layout of a Taxonomy Term Page

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

By default my taxonomy term page lists all articles using this term in 2-columns. I would like to change it to a 1-column layout.

**(1) I have created a custom display layout for the taxonomy group:**

[image]

**(2) And selected the one column layout:**

[image]

Still it doesn't work. Any other changes, like adding a field, do work though. What am I missing?

Note: I did clear the cache.

Comment: Did you clear cache? Is your Taxonomy terms Views Format set to Grid?

Comment: @prkos yes, cache cleared. Regarding the terms views format I'm not sure if you mean this: "Admin -> Structure -> Views -> Taxonomy term -> Format" which is set to "Format:Unformatted list"

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, that's the Format I meant. It's not that then. BTW I'm guessing that the downvote was because there isn't enough info in your question to try to even guess what could be the problem. Try inspecting the column elements with dev tools and see which CSS is laying it out in columns. It may give you some clues. Other than that turn off some modules or settings and see if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the good tips @prkos. You know I'm relatively new to Drupal and there are so many places where you can customize things. Yes analyzing with dev tools I see there is a "grid layout" e.g. `instructor-item col-md-6 col-sm-12`. Where else can this be overriden other than the template level? I guess the latter might be the cause.

Comment: That sounds like classes from Bootstrap. Are you using bootstrap theme? What if you temporarily use a different theme, do you still see the columns?

Comment: Yes, the theme is indeed based on Bootstrap and taking another theme makes it work. Thank you very much! If you reply it as an answer I will accept it. Now i only need to find out why Bootstrap doesn't respect the layout.

Comment: Also the CSS Class "instructor-item" indicates it is using the theme template from another content type which I'm actually not displaying here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@prkos](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/52224/prkos), it turned out that the root of the problem was located inside the Bootstrap Sub-Theme.

Someone created a (hacky) [template override](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163801/pattern-name-for-override-view-templates) for one specific content type in a generic manner. By renaming the file `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` to `views-view-unformatted--SOME-CONTENT.html.twig` it kept the override for the mentioned content item, but also made layouts of other, generic content types work as intended.

Comment: You found it! You should accept this answer, you explained it in a way it will be useful to others :) This shows how a mismatch between configuration and theme templates can create unexpected problems. It's only one of the reasons I dislike Bootstrap :p

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I see, unfortunately some other company made this theme for my company a while ago. OT: What other theming approach would you recommend, while having a responsive basis for the theme?

Comment: I think most if not all themes you can find today are responsive, and there are base themes you can use to build on top of. Bootstrap has many disadvantages in general (this is coming from my own biased opinion of a clean code advocate) but it doesn't mean you can't use it with Drupal and very successfully. Today we have such advanced features that allow you to control the layout through the interface without coding (Layout Builder module). But in your question templates with hard-coded columns/layout were used that overrode LB options. So just be aware of both worlds so they work together.